# Replacing multiple values in a column of a dataframe Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

Thousands of values need to be replaced by a simpler naming format. For example, the original dataframe's naming is AB5648, CD5678, EF5468, etc. and need to be replaced by HH_1, HH_2, HH_3 and so on, in accordance with the correspondence table I created.
Correspondence table includes values to replace and to be replaced.

```
Original file = df_temp 

Filename = 'HH_number_Old.csv'
Filename = 'HH_number_New.csv'

Old                     New
AB1321                 HH_1
CD5678                 HH_2
EF5468                 HH_3
EF5468                 HH_3
EF5438                 HH_4
EF5368                 HH_5
EF5068                 HH_6
EF5468                 HH_7
EF5458                 HH_8
EF5168                 HH_9
.....                 .....
XZ5465                HH_3000
```

Here's what I tried.

```
for i in range (3000):
    print(HH_number_old[i])
    print(HH_number_new[i])

    temp_fin = df_temp.replace({HH_contract[i], HH_no[i]}, inplace=True) 
          #temp_fin is the resultant dataframe with replaced values

Result = temp_fin file is empty.
```

Replacing works when I try a specific number of [i] as below.

```
temp_fin = df_temp.replace (HH_number_old[1], HH_number_new[1])
```

Comment: My solution working?

Comment: @jezreal, yes thank you. But how to do it using the correspondence table, which is another csv. The reason I am trying to use the table is the naming needs to be consistent among several files. If in one file  AB1234 is named HH_1, it should be the same in the others as well.

Comment: My answer was edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.rank`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rank.html):

```
df['new'] = 'HH_' + df['To_be_replaced'].rank(method='dense').astype(int).astype(str)
```

Or [`GroupBy.ngroup`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html):

```
df['new'] = 'HH_' + df.groupby('To_be_replaced', sort=False).ngroup().add(1).astype(str)
```

---

```
print (df)
  To_be_replaced To_replace   new
0         AB1321       HH_1  HH_1
1         CD5678       HH_2  HH_2
2         EF5468       HH_3  HH_3
3         EF5468       HH_3  HH_3
4         EF5468       HH_3  HH_3
5         EF5468       HH_3  HH_3
6         EF5468       HH_3  HH_3
7         EF5468       HH_3  HH_3
8         EF5468       HH_3  HH_3
9         EF5468       HH_3  HH_3
```

EDIT:

For replace multiple another DataFrames use:

```
d = dict(zip(df['To_be_replaced'], df['new']))
```

And then [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) in another DataFrames:

```
df1['new'] = df1['To_be_replaced'].map(d)
df2['new'] = df2['To_be_replaced'].map(d)
```

Answer (score 1):

I see that `EF5468` is being mapped according to your question as both `HH_3` and `HH_7`. I am guessing that this mapping should be unique (importing this as a DataFrame and using dictionary comprehension should create a unique key-value pair).

You can simply use a map for this:

```
mapping_dict = {
'AB1321':                'HH_1', 
'CD5678':                'HH_2', 
'EF5468':                'HH_3',
'EF5438':                'HH_4',
'EF5368':                'HH_5',
'EF5068':                'HH_6',
'EF5458':                'HH_7',
'EF5168':                'HH_8'

df['new'] = df['old'].map(mapping_dict)
```

This should achieve the results you want, assuming that I understood your question correctly (with each ID only occurring once), and there exists a bijective (i.e. one-to-one and onto) mapping from the old ID to new ID.